# Symfony - one message for multiple assert

Tags: regex, symfony, assert

I have :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 8,
 *      minMessage = "message.erreur.affich1"
 * )
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      max = 20,
 *      maxMessage = "message.erreur.affich1"
 * )
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/",
 *      match=true,
 *      message="message.erreur.affich1"
 *
 * )
 */     
private $plainPassword;
```

I want to display 1 single message for these 3 conditions, but I can not.
I have 3 times the same message that appears.

How to do so, to display only 1 error message even if the 3 conditions are not respected?
my only solution might be to do everything in regex ...

Thanks

Comment: unrelated question : why do you have a max length for the password ?

Comment: you could combine min and max in your @Assert\Length when message is the same

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom validation constraint where you would check all three assertions, and apply error message, when needed. To use single custom assertion for all three conditions at once, you need to create a "class" validator that would apply to the whole entity. Here is the link to documentation - http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Either you use a [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) which validates the whole entity and provides a consolidated output as you desire it.
2. You don't fully rely on the way how validation errors are given to a form but use the [validation service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) after the validation errors have been gathered.

Personally I'd go for option 2, but this depends whether you are using Forms / Twig etc, how often you'd need it, whether 'aggregating error messages' is your only required customatization etc.

So if you're not happy with 1 or 2 immediately you'll have to provide us with more details.